# É possível extender o css do bootstrap utilizando less?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

Eu uso o twitter bootstrap para algumas coisas, e me deparei com a facilidade de utilizar o less, como posso fazer, para utilizar as variáveis less do bootstrap num segundo arquivo css?

Por exemplo, chamar as media querys com os valores do bootstrap:

```
@media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {
    #test{
        background-color: #285e8e!important;
    }
}
```

É possível fazer isso em um segundo arquivo, sem modificar o bootstrap.min.css?

Comment: É possível importar um css para outro, mas não encontrei forma de reutilizar um .less

Comment: Veja aqui: http://lesscss.org/features/#import-directives-feature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro você deve utilizar o arquivo Less do Bootstrap ao invés do bootstrap.min.css e no lugar de adicionar o bootstrap no seu HTML você importa no seu arquivo .less com `@import '../caminho-do-seu-bootstrap/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less';` antes das suas definições. Dessa forma o código acima já vai funcionar e você não precisa nem do `!important` já que pela hierarquia o seu CSS ficará por cima.

[Aqui na documentação](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#less) do Bootstrap tem as variáveis que você pode customizar. Com isso você customiza e usa as variáveis no seu arquivo mesmo, depois de fazer o `@import`. Por exemplo, no seu Less ficaria algo assim:

```
@import '../bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less';

@media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {
    #test{
        background-color: #285e8e;
    }
}
```

Apenas como observação, é importante nunca alterar códigos de terceiros, pois pode lhe trazer muitos problemas futuros. Tratando-se de CSS, mesmo que não saiba como, assuma que sempre será possível sobrescrever o código de terceiros ao invés de modificá-los, e aí você tenta descobrir como fazer. Na maioria das vezes basta só inserir seu CSS depois e usar as mesmas classes/variáveis para sobrescrever as propriedades.